# Flash cs6 AS3 Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I just implemented that last piece of code you sent over - many thanks!!
This is the FULL context of this frame, the complete code with the other buttons as well, in case that is causing the problem. The 19 errors I get with this piece of code is:

> 1120: Access of undefined property fl_ProLoader_01

```
 stop();

 //home button

 mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_01_1,false,0,true);

 function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_01_1(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
     removeChild(fl_ProLoader_01);
     fl_ProLoader_01.unloadAndStop();
     fl_ProLoader_01 = null;
 }

 mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_01_1,false,0,true);

 function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_01_1(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    removeChild(fl_ProLoader_01);

 }

 mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToStopAllSounds_01_1,false,0,true);

 function fl_ClickToStopAllSounds_01_1(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
 }

 mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_01_2,false,0,true);

 function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_01_2(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    gotoAndStop(1);
 }

 //other buttons at the bottom

 mythbutt_aboriginal_culture.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_01_1);

 function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_01_1(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.bigmyth.com/fullversion/password033/download/ABORIGINAL_CULTURE.pdf"), "_blank");
 }

 mythbutt_aboriginal_pantheon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_01_2);

 function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_01_2(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.bigmyth.com/fullversion/password033/download/ABORIGINAL_PANTHEON.pdf"), "_blank");
 }

 mythbutt_aboriginal_exercises.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_01_3);

 function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_01_3(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest( "http://www.bigmyth.com/fullversion/password033/download/ABORIGINAL_EXERCISES.pdf"), "_blank");
 }

 //start button

 //Change your event handler function.
 start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToLoadSWF_01_2);

 function fl_ClickToLoadSWF_01_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
     fl_ProLoader_01=new ProLoader  ;
     fl_ProLoader_01.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
     fl_ProLoader_01.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 

         //Using closure callback instead of *onComplete_1* function
         function( e : Event ) { 
                e.currentTarget.content.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, OEF_01);
         });
     addChild(fl_ProLoader_01);
     fl_ProLoader_01.x=323;
     fl_ProLoader_01.y=41;

 //Swap the event handlers,no need for flag,clear code blocks
     start_button_aboriginal.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToLoadSWF_01_2);
     start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_01_2);
 }

 function fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_01_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
     fl_ProLoader_01.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,OEF_01);

     removeChild(fl_ProLoader_01);
     fl_ProLoader_01.unloadAndStop();
     fl_ProLoader_01=null;

     start_button_aboriginal.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_01_2);
 }

 function OEF_01(e:Event):void {
      if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame==e.currentTarget.totalFrames) {
           e.currentTarget.stop();
           fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_01_2(null);
      }
 }
```

Comment: From the sample code you have provided you have two places where you do `removeChild(fl_ProLoader_1)`, but you check if fl_ProLoader_1 is null in only the first place. And then you null it. So if that happens first, and later in code you try to removeChild this object again, then it is still null and thus your error would come up.

Answer (score 2):

I think @GarryWong is right. If you click the *start* button after the *external swf* has been loaded and before his timeline has finished you will get an error.

I've changed your implementation, please try this. 
No need to check for null object.

### UPDATE

---

```
//Change your event handler function.
startbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToLoadSWF_1_2);

function fl_ClickToLoadSWF_1_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    fl_ProLoader_1=new ProLoader();
    fl_ProLoader_1.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
    fl_ProLoader_1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 
                                                      //Using closure callback instead of *onComplete_1* function
                                                      function( e : Event ) {
                                                          e.currentTarget.content.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, OEF_1);
                                                          });
    addChild(fl_ProLoader_1);
    fl_ProLoader_1.x=207;
    fl_ProLoader_1.y=41;

    //Swap the event handlers,no need for flag,clear code blocks
    startbutton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToLoadSWF_1_2);
    startbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_1_2);
}

function fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_1_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    fl_ProLoader_1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,OEF_1);

    removeChild(fl_ProLoader_1);
    fl_ProLoader_1.unloadAndStop();
    fl_ProLoader_1=null;

    startbutton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_1_2);
    //Use the below line only if you want to repeat the procedure of loading the *Proloader*, otherwise omit it.
    startbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToLoadSWF_1_2);
}

function OEF_1(e:Event):void {
    if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame==e.currentTarget.totalFrames) {
        e.currentTarget.stop();
        fl_ClickToUnLoadSWF_1_2(null);
    }
}
```

<del>Sorry but I haven't Flash installed in my PC right now so maybe there will be some mistakes in my code.</del> *You made me boot my Windows partition!*

Comment: hi - thanks so much for your speedy reply! unfortunately I get loads of errors with that code. Can you have another look and update it? thanks!! Fiona

Comment: It would certainly help if you could post the exact error messages you see. Loads of errors is not a very useful reply to someone.

Comment: @FionaPassantino I've change my code, I've forgot the callback function for the `Event.COMPLETE`. Other than that I don't see any other errors. As @PranavNegandhi said we can't do much if you don't post the errors.

Comment: hi - sorry for the delay!! This is the specific error I am getting:      TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at bigmythfree_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_13_1()[bigmythfree_fla.MainTimeline::frame94:18]

Comment: I have just edited the code above and now I get lots of new errors: "1120: Access of undefined property fl_ProLoader_01" Can anyone help?? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @FionaPassantino Why you assign multiple event listeners for the same event to same button?!!! The error it's pretty obvious and it's the same since the first time. Your code is a mess, that's why you can't see it ,*no offence*. You are trying to `removeChild` your `fl_ProLoader_01` which is already removed. If you click the `mythbutt_home` you remove the `fl_ProLoader_01` two times.

Comment: @FionaPassantino I saw another error in my code, `fl_ProLoader_01 = new ProLoader();`